# Factory reset ACR1255U-J1 NFC reader

Tags: bluetooth, nfc, smartcard-reader

Does anyone know how to reset an Advanced Card Systems NFC reader type ACR1255U-J1? I've sent an escape command to it and it got stuck. When I switch the button at the top I get a purple light for LED1 and orange light for LED2 followed by red light for LED1 and no light for LED2. Any help will be appriciated.

I can see the device through Mac Terminal when it is connected through USB but it is no longer visible when bluetooth is on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the ACS1255U-J1 shows the behavior you described it's basically bricked. It happens because of a stack overflow problem (no pun intended) in the readers' firmware and ACS is currently working to correct it. I've seen it happen repeatedly with very long Escape Commands like the Rewrite Master Key Command Request (36 bytes long) as well as some shorter ones. Depending on the severity of the overflow, you may be able to resurrect the reader by reflashing it with fresh firmware. You can download all the stuff you need from our site here:

http://flomio.com/ACR1255U-J1-FlashTool/

You'll need a Win7 machine to work the tool and even then it'll take a few tries to get the reader in DFU mode. If you run into issues, post support questions on [our forums](http://flomio.com/ask-the-flomies) and we'll be happy to help.

That said your device corruption may be beyond repair. This can happen if you've wiped out the boot sector of the flash. You'll know this if the reader fails to enter DFU mode. I've been able to resurrect a few readers but found them lacking some key setting like the serial number field being gone (all zeros). But more just don't enter DFU. We're authorized distributors of ACS products so if you want to RMA your device through us let me know and we can work something out.

UPDATE: Flomio now has the ability to repair bricked ACR1255U-J1 units. You can ping us on [our forums](http://flomio.com/ask-the-flomies) for details.